# function to stream certain name and number from txt file

Tags: c++, function, fstream

i made a file named clientFile.txt
the file contain this [clientFile.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGcZi.png). Content:

```
abcd abcd 123 1607325695
A AI 123 1607327861
```

the function below should show the content of the text file when the function called.

```
void displayFile()
{
    string str1;
    string str2;
    string fileN = "clientFile.txt";
    ifstream myfilein;
    myfilein.open("clientFile.txt");
    double balance;
    int numAct = 0;
    time_t transTime;
    if(!myfilein){
        cerr << "FIle could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while(myfilein >> str1 >> str2 >> balance >> transTime){
        cout << setw(15) << str1 << ' ' << setw(15) << str2 << ' '
        << setw(7) << balance << "  " << ctime(&transTime);
        numAct++;
    }
    myfilein.close();
    cout << "Number of records in the file " << fileN << ": " << numAct << endl;
}
```

but when i call it on this int main:

```
int main(){
    ofstream myfileout;
    ifstream myfilein;
    string firstName,lastName;
    int i=0;
    string FN[1000],LN[1000];
    
    double actBalance,AB[1000];
    time_t currentTime,CT[1000];
    myfilein.open ("clientFile.txt");
    void displayFile();
    if(myfilein.fail()){
        cout<<"Creating new files"<<endl;
        myfileout.open ("clientFile.txt",ios::out);
        myfileout.close();
        exit(1);
    }
    while(myfilein>>firstName>>lastName>>actBalance>>currentTime){
        FN[i]=firstName;
        LN[i]=lastName;
        AB[i]=actBalance;
        CT[i]=currentTime;
        i++;
    }
    myfileout.open("clientFile.txt",ios::app);
    cout<<"Enter first name, last name, and balance:"<<endl;
    while(cin>>firstName>>lastName>>actBalance){
         createRecord(myfileout, firstName,lastName,actBalance);
    
    }
    void displayFile();
    myfileout.close();
}
```

it didnt show me any of the file content.
can you guys help me?
im using dev c++ with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit release

Comment: Would strongly suggest a `stuct` holding each client's information and then use `std::vector<struct name>` instead of individual arrays for each bit of info coordinated by index (fragile) Then you could overload `ifstream` and `ofstream` and have the input handled with a single `>>`.

Comment: This is a **typo**: you declared `displayFile` instead of calling it at the end of `main()`.

Answer (score -1):

In last lines of main() you just need to change

```
void displayFile();
```

to

```
displayFile();
```

Because with `void` you're declaring a function, not calling it.

Comment: Typos are generally handled by comment + VTC.